# NSAssert vs NSCAssert

Tags: ios, objective-c, assert, nsassert

What is the difference between `NSAssert` and `NSCAssert`? When I explored their implementation they looked very similar and I couldn't find an answer to my question.

I guess that it will also explain the difference between `NSParameterAssert` and `NSCParameterAssert`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The second is the difference between C and Objective-C assertions:
>   NSAssert should only be used in an Objective-C context (i.e. method
>   implementations), whereas NSCAssert should only be used in a C context
>   (i.e. functions).

More at http://nshipster.com/nsassertionhandler/

Answer (score 6):

Note that using NSAssert/NSParameterAssert within a block may cause a retain cycle. Use the C variants instead. Google NSAssert retain cycle

Answer (score 3):

This is taken from NSHipster, see [link](http://nshipster.com/nsassertionhandler/)

> Foundation defines two pairs of assertion macros:
>
> `NSAssert/NSCAssert`
>
> `NSParameterAssert/NSCParameterAssert`
>
> Foundation makes two distinctions in their assertion handler APIs that
>   are both semantic and functional.
>
> The first distinction is between a general assertion (`NSAssert`) and a parameter assertion (`NSParameterAssert`). As a rule of thumb,
>   methods / functions should use `NSParameterAssert/NSCParameterAssert`
>   statements at the top of methods to enforce any preconditions about
>   the input values; in all other cases, use `NSAssert/NSCAssert`.
>
> The second is the difference between C and Objective-C assertions: `NSAssert` should only be used in an Objective-C context
>   (i.e. method implementations), whereas NSCAssert should only be used
>   in a C context (i.e. functions).

Answer (score 2):

NSAssert should only be used in an Objective-C context and NSCAssert should only be used in a C context (i.e. functions).